# 'Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. even though the button inside a form with runat ="server"

Tags: c#, render

I'm getting Control 'Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. even though the button inside a form with runat ="server".Please help

```
 public string RenderControlToHtml(Control ControlToRender)
    {
        if (this.Form.Controls.Contains(ControlToRender))
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            System.IO.StringWriter stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stWriter);
            ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            //ControlToRender.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
      }
```

Adding markup, This controls are inside form with runat="server"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
           <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#EEECE1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel0" runat="server" Text="First Name" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#EEECE1"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
             </tr>

              <tr>
                <td> <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" Text="DOB" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>  <asp:TextBox ID="DOBBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#EEECE1"></asp:TextBox></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td> <asp:Label ID="MEMBIDLabel" runat="server" Text="Beneficiary ID" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label></td>
                <td> <asp:TextBox ID="MEMBIDBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#EEECE1"></asp:TextBox> </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PCPLabel" runat="server" Text="Aligned Provider" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PCPBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#EEECE1"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="HospLabel" runat="server" Text="Hospital" CssClass="MemberInfolabel"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you've shown likely isn't relevant.  You would want to show your HTML and ASP.NET markup.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Actually, the code shown is relevant. The problem is that the form is not being rendered, which *almost* always means the control is not part of a form, but manually calling `RenderControl` causes the same behaviour.

Comment: I have added the markup please check, my intention is to convert the page to pdf using itextsharp.. normall methods are not working I have tried html parser but it throws error with link button...So thought of passing only the controls which I need...This is only a sample.